# three.js in chrome 86 appear lots of white line

Tags: three.js

this problem in chrome 120 is normal,but in chrome 86 appear lots of white lines cover the map,i just add color in map[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkPSn.jpg)

Browsers are webgl-compatible,i use MeshBasicMaterial appear this problem.